# What are the most notable new things in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

What are the most notable new features and things in Black Ops, not available in Modern Warfare 2 and previous CoDs? E.g. I heard you can change your outfit.

Comment: I don't think we're qualified to predict the future...

Comment: As @tzenes mentioned, we prefer to stay away from questions about future releases. See [Asking about upcoming game releases](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231/the-grace-is-always-right)

Comment: IMHO It's an excellent question. Why should I buy Black Ops when I bought Modern Warfare II 4 months ago ? Which benefits will I get to buy Black Ops ?

Comment: While I agree in principle, Black Ops is out in just a month or so. A lot is already know about the game, including perks and weapons, new game modes, and new features like points and character customization.

Comment: @Luc because we have no way of knowing what Black Ops may or may not contain, we can't tell what benefits there are to buying it.  Certainly there has been a lot of information release, but this would not be the [first time](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Unused_units) a company has released information that did not make it to the final game.

Comment: There is certainly precedence for asking about features in games that haven't been released.  Someone can list what is known at this point, and update it as needed.  As long as we stick to confirmed features and not speculative wish lists, I think it is OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. No Stopping Power or Juggernaut type perks.
2. Killstreaks are not stackable.  You will have to earn all the killstreak rewards yourself
3. Theater mode.  You can actually record gameplay without a capture card
4. Sleight of Hand Pro will not increase the speed of aiming down sights for sniper rifles
5. All snipers rifles with be one-hit kills from the chest up.
6. You can actually see what your character will look like based on the tier 1 perk you choose.
7. Wager match game types: Sticks and Stones, Sharpshooter, One in the chamber and Gun Game
8. Combat Training -- You can play computer controlled bots on multiplayer maps
9. Some multiplayer maps have interactive environments
10. Scavenger will only resupply ammunition and lethal grenades
11. The equipment slot
12. Regional Match Making - It will be easier to find player closer to you
13. Customizable game mode - You can now share these types of games with other players
14. Weapons Prestige - Your weapons can now prestige like players can.

Answer (score 3):

Without a doubt, the most interesting "new" feature in Black Ops is the currency system. Basically, you earn "money" for completing rounds that can be used by buy weapon/skill/etc unlocks. Instead of unlocking them at set levels, you can buy the unlocks whenver you want as long as you have enough money. They are even going to have special match times where you can bet your money that you'll win and potentially win even more. A quick Google returned this:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Call-of-Duty-Black-Ops-Has-Internal-Currency-System-for-Multiplayer-155186.shtml

But I'm sure you could find some better links if you looked for them. Other than that, the weapons, perks, and kill streaks are all pretty similar to previous ones with very minor changes only. This is definitely a place where Treyarch is doing something new.

Answer (score 2):

- Change face paint
- Have your clan tag etched on your weapon

Answer (score 0):

Check out this episode of GTTV. It is all about Black Ops, both single player and multi player.

http://www.gametrailers.com/episode/gametrailers-tv/106

There is some stuff in the multi-player section that would almost convince me to buy (not that I was going to anyway).